# Porting existing ASP.NET MVC web sites to DNX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, dnx, dnvm

How do you port an existing ASP.NET MVC web site to build with DNX to make it cross platform?

Ideally I'd like to be able to build it with VSCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there isn't automatic conversion tool.
You have to create an ASP.NET 5 WebSite Project and import your Views, Controllers, Classes, etc. manually